You need to accept the user’s message in aiogram after the bot’s message has been sent
My bot sends a message like “enter the quantity to exchange:” and I need to accept the message that the user sent after this message.
I tried through "message.text" but I was getting the previous message from the user, i.e. "Exchange"
@router.message(F.text == " Exchange")
async def exchange(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    State.id = msg.from_user.id
    State.first_name = msg.from_user.first_name
    State.last_name = msg.from_user.last_name
    State.is_premium = msg.from_user.is_premium
    State.is_bot = msg.from_user.is_bot
    await msg.answer('Enter the amount what u need to exchange:')
    need_message = msg.text
    print(need_message)
    await state.set_state(UserState.exchange_amount)
    
@router.message(UserState.exchange_amount)
async def exchange_amount_handler(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    amount = msg.text
    print(f"You enter {amount} clicks?")
    await state.clear()

github repository: https://github.com/neforskiy/pythonBotClicker

aiogram version?

my aiogram version 3.6 seems to be

You need to work around Finite State Machine(FSM), built in aiogram
first things first: configuring storage
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage


storage = MemoryStorage() # memory storage as an example.

dp = Dispatcher(storage=storage)

then you need to make states group
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup

class UserState(StatesGroup):
    exchange_amount = State()

then you need to modify your existing handler
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext

@router.message(F.text == " Exchange") # no need to filter state here
async def exchange(msg: Message, state: FSMContext): # adding state var
    State.id = msg.from_user.id  # idk what is this State you are using
    State.first_name = msg.from_user.first_name  # so I will keep your code untouched
    State.last_name = msg.from_user.last_name
    State.is_premium = msg.from_user.is_premium
    State.is_bot = msg.from_user.is_bot
    await msg.answer('Enter the amount of clicks what u want to exchange to $NOT: ')
    need_message = msg.text
    print(need_message)
    await state.set_state(UserState.exchange_amount) # setting state to filter incoming message

then you need a handler to handle different state and new message
@router.message(UserState.exchange_amount)
async def exchange_amount_handler(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    amount = msg.text
    ... # do whatever you need
    await state.clear() # clear state to enable main menu options or set another to continue routing

more info on states: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/index.html

when i called "python main.py" i get a TypeError:
TypeError: unsupported callable

what Traceback?
PS E:\PythonBotClicker> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 1384, in getfullargspec
sig = _signature_from_callable(func,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 2491, in _signature_from_callable
raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: <states.State object at 0x000001A836024530> is not a callable object

it? or i stupid?

update code in question, what you having atm

so, i edit my code in question, what u can say about this?

aiogram version?

my aiogram version 3.6 seems to be

I was wrong, version 3.12

never the less. I can't tell what's wrong by only this piece of code.

what? 3.11? why i have it from command "pip show aiogram": Name: aiogram
Version: 3.12.0

so, maybe i add the full code? But all text in the code on russian speak. Do u need it for help me?

github link would do

i've edit my post and add github link

THX u, i have a mistake in my states.py code. I set class State(), but this State will be imported and used  in next class. Ur answer help me.  Thx u, man
